# Caching PWA Files on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have made a Progressive Web App (PWA) that runs on Android and iOS and needs to function without any internet connection. Obviously this is one of the key benefits of a PWA using a service worker, but I have run into a little problem with Apple devices.

When a new user first "installs" the app on an iPhone or iPad it doesn't immediately work offline. The app has to be opened first with an internet connection and thereafter it does work offline. Presumably this is because the service worker doesn't create the cache at the time of "install" but only when the app is opened.

The service worker (more or less copied from online sources) is

```
const cacheName = 'v0.54';
const contentToCache = [
    'index.html',
    'before.html',
    'scoring.html',
    'check.html',
    'correction.html',
    'after.html',
    'help.html',
    'register.js',
    'manifest.json',
    'css/style.min.css',
    'css/ace-responsive-menu.min.css',
    '/js/ace-responsive-menu.min.js',
    '/js/jquery.js',
    '/fonts/Merriweather-Regular.woff',
    '/fonts/Merriweather-Bold.woff',
    '/images/bike.png',
    '/images/littlehotels.png',
    '/images/share.svg',
    '/fav/apple-touch-icon.png',
    '/fav/browserconfig.xml',
    '/fav/favicon-32x32.png',
    '/fav/favicon-16x16.png',
    '/fav/favicon.ico',
    '/fav/safari-pinned-tab.svg',
    '/fav/maskable_icon.png',
    '/fav/android-chrome-192x192.png',
    '/fav/android-chrome-512x512.png'
];


/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener("install", (e) => {
    console.log("[Service Worker] Install");
    e.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        console.log("[Service Worker] Caching all: app shell and content");
        await cache.addAll(contentToCache);
    })()
    );
});

/* Clear any old caches */
self.addEventListener("activate", (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
        return Promise.all(
        keyList.map((key) => {
            if (key === cacheName) {
                return;
            }
            return caches.delete(key);
        })
        );
    })
    );
});

/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener("fetch", (e) => {
    e.respondWith(
    (async () => {
        const r = await caches.match(e.request);
        console.log(`[Service Worker] Fetching resource: ${e.request.url}`);
        if (r) {
            return r;
        }
        const response = await fetch(e.request);
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        console.log(`[Service Worker] Caching new resource: ${e.request.url}`);
        cache.put(e.request, response.clone());
        return response;
    })()
    );
});
```

I know that Apple support for PWAs falls a long way short of Google, so I am guessing that iOS is not executing the *self.addEventListener("install", (e) => {*. iOS doesn't really "install" the app but just creates a shortcut on the Home Screen, so is there an alternative event listener that would create the cache at the time of creating the shortcut?

EDIT
On further thought and searching, I came up with the idea of using the WebShare API to implement Add to Home Screen on an Apple device. I created a button on the page and then added this short experimental piece of Javascript

```
  const shareButton = document.querySelector('.ios-prompt');
  shareButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
      if (navigator.share) {
          navigator.share({
              title: 'Trial Observer Scoresheet',
              url: 'https://mototrial.co.uk/observer/'
          });
      } else {
          // fallback
      }
  });
```

Because I would be using Javascript, I was hoping I could use it to also cache the app contents by copying part of the code from the service worker. I don't know if it would have worked because I didn't get that far. Although the navigator.share appeared to be working, it provided a greatly reduced list of available shares and in particular, it didn't have Add to Home Screen.